# boolean expression for Where

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am filtering data using nullable variable.
If the variable is null the the filter is off.
Is there any nicer way to write:

```
GetQuery().Where(pd=> (!customerId.HasValue || pd.CustomerId==customerId.Value))
```

(I have more then 4 filters and it looks like a huge block of mess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn’t a nicer way to write the same. However, I have to say that for the logic you want (which is not the standard meaning of `null` in a Nullable type) it is quite short. I don’t think you can expect to get any shorter.

I don’t find it particularly unreadable or messy, even if you had 4 or even 10 copies of that line underneath each other. The shortest I can think of is this:

```
GetQuery().Where(pd => customerId == null || pd.CustomerId == customerId)
          .Where(pd => customerName == null || pd.CustomerName == customerName)
          .Where(pd => customerAddress == null || pd.CustomerAddress == customerAddress)
          .Where(pd => customerPostcode == null || pd.CustomerPostcode == customerPostcode)
          .Where(pd => customerCountry == null || pd.CustomerCountry == customerCountry)
          .Where(pd => customerPhoneNumber == null || pd.CustomerPhoneNumber == customerPhoneNumber)
```

Comment: I actually used .Where(pd=> ... && ... && ...) and not Where for each condition. Does it hurt efficiency?

Comment: @Naor: It makes no mentionable difference. If this is LINQ-to-SQL, then it even makes no difference *at all*.

Comment: I can't speak to efficiency, but I'd definitely chain LINQ extension methods before combining a large number of conditions in one anonymous predicate...

Answer (score 3):

Your example:

```
GetQuery().Where(pd=> (!customerId.HasValue || pd.CustomerId==customerId.Value))
```

could be written using the null coalescing operator `??`:

```
GetQuery().Where( pd => pd.CustomerID == ( customerId ?? pd.CustomerID ) )
```

Not sure if it improves things, but it's an option.

Comment: That's interesting, though you I believe you mean to have `customerId ?? pd.CustomerID` wrapped in parens, otherwise it would be an invalid expression (in general).

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought `??` would bind tighter than `==`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might use an extension method to build it up.

```
public static IQueryable<T> OptionalWhere<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int? id, Expression<Func<T, int, bool>> filter)
{
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        var idValue = id.Value;
        query = query.Where(e => filter(e, idValue));
    }
    return query;
}
```

Then the query in becomes:

```
var q = GetQuery().OptionalWhere(customerId, (pd, id) => pd.CustomerId == id);
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this method for each nullable type (long?, int?, string and so on)?

Comment: @Naor Nullable types (that doesn't include `string`) are instances of [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). You could always make the type of the `id` parameter `Nullable<T>` (though again, that doesn't help you deal with strings).

Comment: You can't magically invoke an expression like that... you'd have to rebuild it.